# How do I auto size columns through the Excel interop objects?

Tags: c#, excel-2003, excel-interop

Below is the code I'm using to load the data into an Excel worksheet, but I'm look to auto size the column after the data is loaded.  Does anyone know the best way to auto size the columns?

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;

public class ExportReport
{
    public void Export()
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb;
        Excel.Worksheet ws;
        Excel.Range aRange;
        object m = Type.Missing;
        string[,] data;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (excelApp == null)
                throw new Exception("EXCEL could not be started.");

            // Create the workbook and worksheet.
            wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Office.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            ws = (Office.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

            if (ws == null)
                throw new Exception("Could not create worksheet.");

            // Set the range to fill.
            aRange = ws.get_Range("A1", "E100");

            if (aRange == null)
                throw new Exception("Could not get a range.");

            // Load the column headers.
            data = new string[100, 5];
            data[0, 0] = "Column 1";
            data[0, 1] = "Column 2";
            data[0, 2] = "Column 3";
            data[0, 3] = "Column 4";
            data[0, 4] = "Column 5";

            // Load the data.
            for (int row = 1; row < 100; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                {
                    data[row, col] = "STUFF";
                }
            }

            // Save all data to the worksheet.
            aRange.set_Value(m, data);
            // Atuo size columns
            // TODO: Add Code to auto size columns.

            // Save the file.
            wb.SaveAs("C:\Test.xls", Office.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, m, m, m, m, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, m, m, m, m, m);
            // Close the file.
            wb.Close(false, false, m);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            // Close the connection.
            cmd.Close();
            // Close Excel.
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Add this at your TODO point:

`aRange.Columns.AutoFit();`

Comment: There is also a `aRange.Rows.AutoFit()` as well.

Comment: Use the @nawfal answer: aRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: `AutoFit()` does not put the columns into a mode where they automatically adjust to content that you add later, but does a once only fit with the current data. So the `Range` must be completely populated before calling `AutoFit()`.

Comment: Here is another good one:  workSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();

Answer (score 47):

This might be too late but if you add

```
 worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

or

```
 worksheet.Rows.AutoFit();
```

it also works.

Comment: I like this better. This is more useful if you don't care about specific columns that need to be resized and just want the whole sheet to be autofit.

Answer (score 30):

Also there is

```
aRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

See [What is the difference between Range.Columns and Range.EntireColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058062/see-the-difference-between-range-columns-and-range-entirecolumn).

Answer (score 3):

This method opens already created excel file, Autofit all columns of all sheets based on **3rd Row**. As you can see Range is selected From **"A3 to K3"** in excel.

```
 public static void AutoFitExcelSheets()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excel = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;
        try
        {
            string ExcelPath = ApplicationData.PATH_EXCEL_FILE;
            _excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            _excel.Visible = false;
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = true;
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            excelWorkbook = _excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath,
                   0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                   true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet currentSheet in excelSheets)
            {
                string Name = currentSheet.Name;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(Name);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCells =
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A3", "K3");
                excelCells.Columns.AutoFit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ProjectLog.AddError("EXCEL ERROR: Can not AutoFit: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            excelWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            releaseObject(excelWorkbook);
            releaseObject(_excel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article, it's not an exact match to your problem, but suits it:

- [Craig Murphy - Excel – wordwrap row autosize issue](http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=242)