# What is the difference between Range.Columns and Range.EntireColumn

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim r as Range
Set r = Range("C2:D3")

Dim r1 as Range, r2 as Range
Set r1 = r.EntireColumn
Set r2 = r.Columns
```

Won't both ranges represent the range "C:D"? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8):

No, EntireColumn represents the range "C:D", Columns represents the columns of the cells in the range.  If you want to see this in action, here's a small sub that shows this.  Place non-zero values in the entire range C2:D3, then place some in C5 and D5.  The values in C5 and D5 won't change with Columns (range1), now substitute EntireColumn (range2) and see what happens.

```
Sub Test()

Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range

    Set range1 = Range("C2:D3").Columns
    Set range2 = Range("C2:D3").EntireColumn

    range1.Value = 0

End Sub
```

Also, `Columns` is indexed, so you can reference the first column like:

```
r.Columns(1)
```

Comment: So Range("C2:D3") and Range("C2:D3").Columns represent the exact same set of cells? So a "Range" object can't simply be defined by the set of cells that it contains? (as Range("C2:D3") and Range("C2:D3").Columns cover the same set of cells but are different)

Comment: There are many ways a Range can be defined.  You can look at the details of the object in the code editor.  You do this by putting the code in a sub, set a breakpoint at the end, then in the Watch window setting a watch for the Range.  Then you can look at all the gory details.

Comment: Good answer. The documentation doesn't make it clear about `Columns`. I think the naming `Columns` is confusing and quite useless. `EntireColumn` is mostly what one needs.