# OLEDB Excel file format

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
                 fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMES=1;\"";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
{
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(getCreateTableCommand(dt), conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}

/*method - getCreateTableCommand returns something like this - 
{CREATE TABLE [Results] ([name1] STRING,[name2] STRING,[name3] STRING,[name4] STRING}*/
```

Output is GOOD. Issue is- I want the excel columns to have proper width. In other words, I want to get wider columns sometimes even wider then the space required to write columns' name. How to resize the column?

Answer (score 0):

The ACE Driver has no control over how Excel displays the value.  If you want to control the cell formatting, you will need to use the [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), a Third Party Add-In like [jetCell](http://devtriogroup.com/ExcelJetcell/Default.aspx), or Excel Automation using the Primary Interop Assembly, but chances are you don't want to go with the last option.

Answer (score 0):

After populating Excel, write a method to autofit the column widths, or set them explicitly in the code to whatever you want. You'd need to use the Excel Interop, and from what I hear, it's a pain in C#. However, this is a pretty simple task and I suspect would not be a big deal in C#. My experience with Excel automation lies solely with vb. This is what I'd do (I don't like using 3rd party anything in my apps though)

[How do I auto size columns through the Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884356/how-do-i-auto-size-columns-through-the-excel-interop-objects)