# How do I auto size columns through the Excel interop objects in AX 2012?

Tags: excel, interop, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Hi I am working in Microsoft Dynamic AX 2012.

How do I auto size columns through the Excel interop objects in ax 2012?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2884596/4509):

```
aRange.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Why should AX be any different?