# Excel how to fit text in cell, based on cell witdh

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to set the witdh of a cell in my ExcelSheet.

Set the witdh:

```
worksheet.Columns["K"].ColumnWidth = 114.80;
```

When the text is larger then the ColumnWith the text is not visible.

I want to split the text to a new row in the same cell based on the ColumnWith.

I tried to add \r\n to the string in the Excel but no result.

**EDIT after answers**

This works perfectly:

```
 worksheet.Columns["K"].ColumnWidth = 114;
 Excel.Range rangeK = worksheet.get_Range("K1");
 rangeK.EntireColumn.WrapText = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is this:

```
worksheet.Range("K1:K100").WrapText = True;
```

That code, for example, will set the cells from K1 to K100 to wrap the contents inside their cells.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options. The first option (which is what I would suggest) is to [autoresize the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884356/how-do-i-auto-size-columns-through-the-excel-interop-objects).

```
worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

The next option is to word wrap all text, which I have not done but [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821514.aspx) might be of use to you. I hope this helps.