# Export to excel autofit rows not working with c#

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms-designer, windowsformshost

Currently, I am using

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

to help me with the export to excel but how can I set it to auto-size the cell rather then the user do not have to resize then they can read all the words in excel

I have used

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit();
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();
```

but they are not helpful enough

[Current Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdC4p.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a range and then you can use

```
aRange.Columns.AutoFit();
```

See the [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884356/how-do-i-auto-size-columns-through-the-excel-interop-objects)

**or you can use**

```
worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

or

```
worksheet.Rows.AutoFit();
```